Any ideas why the code for this cube syncs with the rotation of the headset in VR but not on anything else?
I'm working on a project in AFrame/Three.JS with VR using croquet to have events sync between multiple users. When the user enters VR I switch the camera position and send an event to the model within croquet to process. The code for my function within the Croquet Model is below:
 this.camera = document.querySelector('#camera');
      var cameraObject = camera.object3D;
      this.rotation = {x: THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(this.camera.object3D.rotation.x),
                       y: THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(this.camera.object3D.rotation.y),
                       z: THREE.MathUtils.radToDeg(this.camera.object3D.rotation.z)};

      //camera.setAttribute('look-controls-enabled', 'true');
      //this.rotation = camera.getAttribute('rotation');
      

      
          // Apply the camera's rotation to the cube
      this.rotatingCube.setAttribute('rotation', this.rotation);
      this.future(500).vrEnter();
      console.error("VR ENTER");
      console.error(this.rotation);

To clarify a few things, the code does exactly what it should on the VR headset, I can see the cube matching the rotation of the headset depending on the way that I look. However, checking the console logs on my laptop I'm getting the same rotational value of (0, 380, 0) for every time it logs it, and the cube is not reflecting the headset's position on any device besides the VR headset. And to clarify, instead of console. log I'm using console.error to make it easier for me to differentiate the log messages that come in.
Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated, I've hit a wall trying to figure out how to do this and it's one of the last things I need to do in my project.
